# Signalling error in "expandable context"

Tags: errors, expansion, package-writing

I'm reviewing a few old macros of mine to make them fully expandable. One of the macros takes one argument, which should either be a two-digit or a four-digit integer (>1955). The macro then converts two-digit numbers to four-digit years in the range 1956-2055, and then goes on to do some other stuff (basically based on the difference between current year and the given year). I want to make this expandable since I want to be able to use it in for example `\href{mailto:foo\mymacro{98}bar@example.com}{Mail me!}`.

Now, reviewing the code, I can see that I used lots of assignments, but using `\numexpr` I can get rid of all of this, although at the cost of making the same computation several times as I branch through the different cases.

But I also used to have a bit of sanity checking: If `#1` is greater than 99 but smaller than 1956, I issue a `\PackageError` explaining the problem. If the sanity check holds, this is simply skipped, so its non-expandability is not a problem. Also, when used in ordinary text, the error works as expected. However, inside `\href`, the error becomes

```
Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
```

which is not very helpful.

Is there a way to provide the user with an indication of the problem?

PS: I'm not sure if "expandable context" is the right way to describe the situation. Feel free to suggest a better title.

*Edit:* As an example, assume I want `\mymacro` to expand to the absolute value of the difference between the given year and `\year`. If the input is less than 100, we should interpret it as a year in the range 1956-2055. Input in the range 100-1955 should give an error. What I have now is something like

```
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1>1955 %
    \ifnum\numexpr\year-#1\relax<0 %
      \number\numexpr#1-\year\relax
    \else
      \number\numexpr\year-#1\relax
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum#1>99 %
      ERROR!%
    \else
      \ifnum#1>56 % 19xx
        \number\numexpr\year - 19#1\relax
      \else % 20xx
        \ifnum\numexpr\year - 20#1\relax<0 
          \number\numexpr20#1 - \year\relax
        \else
          \number\numexpr\year - 20#1\relax
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

%\def\test#1{#1: a\mymacro{#1}b}
\def\test#1{#1: \href{http://a\mymacro{#1}b}{Link}}
\test{96} \test{1996}; \test{08} \test{2008}; \test{11} \test{2011};
\test{20} \test{2020}

\test{123}
```

(the a and b are just there to check that spaces don't creep in). So I'd like to replace ERROR! by something which tells the user about the problem, preferably using a message that includes the offending `#1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, since the expansion of `\mymacro` should always be something that can be interpreted by `\href` as a link and `\PackageError` isn't.

You can test if you are inside the argument of `\href` by checking whether the catcode of `%` is 13:

```
\ifnum\catcode`\%=\active\else\PackageError{...}{...}{...}\fi
```

but I don't know how robust is this code. Can you show the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Choosing an answer to accept wasn't trivial: I used both this and Joseph's suggestion. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 8):

The best approach I think is to use a deliberately undefined but well-named control sequence. Something like

```
\ifnum\SomeVar>100\relax
  \expandafter\SignalError
\fi

...

\begingroup
\catcode`\!=11\relax
\catcode`\ =11\relax%
\gdef\SignalError{%
  \ Input too big!%
}%
\endgroup%
```

Done using a catcode 11 space, you'll get an error which at least has some description but which does not crash inside an `\edef`. You might need to adjust the number of letters you use to get it to look 'nice', but this is usually not too hard.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Joseph's answer, but allows any error message (I will use it soon in a package which I try to make very robust about wrong input).

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11\relax
\newcommand{\fp@error@aux}[1]
  {\romannumeral \numexpr 0\@firstofone{\fp@error: #1}}
\newcommand{\fp@error}[1]
  {\expandafter\fp@error@aux\csname fp info: #1\endcsname}

\fp@error{wrong input (123)}
```

Giving

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fp@error: 
                      \fp info: wrong input (123)
```

Here, `\csname fp info: #1\endcsname` builds a control sequence from the characters between `\csname` and `\endcsname`. TeX does not leave it undefined: instead, it is turned into `\relax`, which will not cause an error. Instead, we put an undefined control sequence nearby. `\@firstofone` improves the formatting of the error message, since the undefined control sequence `\fp@error:` is now alone with our `\relax`-ed control sequence in an `<argument>`. Finally, we need a clean way of getting rid of `\relax`, and `\romannumeral\numexpr0` does a good job at this.

EDIT: a few months after that answer, we added `\msg_expandable_error:n` to LaTeX3. This command takes one (braced) argument and displays it (without expanding it). If the user inserts some material (answering `I...` to TeX's prompt), that material is inserted after cleaning up the eror message.

Answer (score 1):

You could define `\mymacro` to expand to be empty when the argument is out-of-range and wrap `\href` in a macro that would test for emptiness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\mymacro#1{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1>1955 %
    \ifnum\numexpr\year-#1\relax<0 %
      \number\numexpr#1-\year\relax
    \else
      \number\numexpr\year-#1\relax
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum#1>99 %
      % out-of-range error!
    \else
      \ifnum#1>56 % 19xx
        \number\numexpr\year - 19#1\relax
      \else % 20xx
        \ifnum\numexpr\year - 20#1\relax<0 
          \number\numexpr20#1 - \year\relax
        \else
          \number\numexpr\year - 20#1\relax
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
%\def\test#1{#1: a\mymacro{#1}b}
\def\test#1{#1: \href{http://a\mymacro{#1}b}{Link}}
\test{96} \test{1996}; \test{08} \test{2008}; \test{11} \test{2011};
\test{20} \test{2020}

\def\hrefwrap#1{\def\tmpi{\mymacro{#1}}\if\relax\tmpi\relax 
\typeout{error! (#1 out of range)}ERROR\footnote{#1 out of range}\else
\href{http://a\tmpi b}{Link}\fi}

\def\testi#1{#1: \hrefwrap{#1}}

\testi{96} \testi{1996}; \testi{08} \testi{2008}; \testi{11} \testi{2011};
\testi{20} \testi{2020}
\testi{123}

%\the\year
\end{document}
```